# Unable to run mysqli_num_rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I am unable to run `mysqli_num_rows` query.

The `if` statement is working on `mysqli_query` but when i proceed to `mysqli_num_rows` its not working and `echo` the `else` statement.

I am working on a Login system and just want to verify the email address exists in the database or not.

Here is my Index.php:

```
<?php
  include "connect.php";
  include "functions.php";

  $email = $password = "";
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
  }
  echo $email .$password;

  if (email_exist($conn,$email)) {
    echo "success"; 
  } else {
    echo "failed";
  }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Login Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login">
      <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <b>Email:</b><br>
        <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
        <b>Password:</b><br>
        <input type="text" name="password"><br><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and functions.php:

```
<?php 
  function email_exist($conn,$email){
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
      echo "Good work";
    } else {
      echo "dont";
    }
  } 
?>
```

Comment: to make sure only 1 result is in the database for that specific email.

Answer (score 0):

This question is off topic, because questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Sadly, but this rule doesn't work, producing forum-like discussions in the comments and guesswork-based answers, which in turn, are essentially off topic too.

All can be answered to your question is:

you are "running" mysqli_num_rows() all right. The problem is your context, which is totally unknown to the reader, and there are no means to answer your question, save for the debugging that can be done only by you.

So, start debugging your code, verifying all the values, and the database contents in the first place.